# Strange Black border around drawable android XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I am drawing custom header to input information in my app. I have drawn 2 shapes in xml and then positioned them in a layout. That layout is then put in my main layout using . However there is a black border that is drawn around each of the included headers. This seems to only be on api 21 devices. What is going on?

**circle.xml**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/icon_background"
    android:shape="oval">
    <padding
        android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/color_primary"
        android:angle="270">
    </solid>
</shape>
```

**line.xml**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke android:width="5dp"
        android:color="@color/color_primary"/>

    <size android:height="10dp" />
</shape>
```

**Header layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/line">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_icon"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_car"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Included layout**

```
<RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/header_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/header_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/header_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/header_vertical_margin">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/carSpecs"
            layout="@layout/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </include>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/header_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/header_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/vehicleSpinner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/carSpecs"/> ...
```

[image: Screenshot!]

Comment: Is this occurring on all devices? Have you tested on the Android emulator?

Comment: I notice it on api21 devices. Lower api's seem fine.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on the 5.0.1 emulator or on a Nexus device given your sample XML. I did need to change the height of the ImageView containing the line drawable to wrap_content or 10dp, though, for the drawable to fit correctly.

Comment: It seems like the first include is fine. However when I reuse the same header 2 or more times the second and third will have the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Using same basis as @Der Golem I removed the

```
<size android:height="10dp" />
```

from the line.xml. Since the stroke was half of the size I was receiving the border. Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this `<solid android:color="#00FFFFFF"/>` in your line.xml.

Comment: Nope it still has the border. One this Ive noticed is that the border shows when I include the header more than once. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:

```
<stroke android:width="5dp"
    android:color="@color/color_primary"/>
```

From `line.xml`

This is adding the extra "border", using the `color_primary` color resource as defined in your colors.xml.